# Disable Cell Editing or Make Cell Readonly

Tags: handsontable

When the user types a value in a cell of a certain column, I would like to make the cell of the next column(same row), readonly ou not editable. If the user deletes de value, I would like to make the next cell editable again.

Can someone give an example of how to achive this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define your columns like this:

```
const hot = new Handsontable(el, {
  data: someData,
  columns: [
    { type: 'text'},
    { type: 'numeric'},
    { type: 'text'}
  ]
});
```

You can update the settings like this

```
hot.updateSettings({
    columns: [
      { type: 'text'},
      { type: 'text', readOnly: true},
      { type: 'text'}
    ]
});
```